# How can I assign Raster2 pixel value to Raster1 where they overlay?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, raster-calculator

I want to assign Raster2 pixel value to Raster1 (bigger) where they overlay. Both of them have the same cell size.

How can I accomplish this process in ArcGIS Desktop? (Like Raster Calculator)

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution in Raster Calculator:

```
Over(Con(IsNull("raster1"),0,"raster1"),"raster2")
```